# Using MOV to protect device for heater element

Tags: inductance, solid-state-relay, surge-protection, mov

I have a heater element that is controlled by a solid state relay from main power. I know it is customary to place a MOV in parallel when switching inductive loads to clamp the voltage to prevent damage when turning off the load. Is this completely unnecessary for resistive loads?

Besides that, I want to protect my circuit from voltage surges from the main so I will put a MOV anyways. I was wondering if I should get a larger MOV (more joules) to take into account the potential overvoltage from switching the heater element.

From the manufacturer, the SSR recommends putting a MOV in parallel. Considering the only inductance I have is from the copper wire which ends up being somewhere around 50 microhenries and using a zero crossing ssr, I feel like the overvoltage will be negigible but I am not sure. This will run on AC main power and 600A and my SSR is plenty overspecced. (rated to run at 1200AC but using 480AC).

Comment: You may want to use multiple MOVs i.e. across L-N and across L-PE and N-PE, if your system has PE (protective earth) connection.

Answer (score 0):

> *I know it is customary to place a MOV in parallel when switching
> inductive loads to clamp the voltage to prevent damage when turning
> off the load. Is this completely unnecessary for resistive loads?*

You need the MOV because even though the load may be resistive, the wiring will have inductance that can cause a back-emf when the SSR deactivates. This applies to MOSFET based SSRs.

> *From the manufacturer, the SSR recommends putting a MOV in parallel.*

I would follow what the manufacturer of the SSR recommends.

> *using a zero crossing ssr*

If that means that the SSR switches off on the **zero cross of the current** (i.e. it is a triac-based SSR) then sure, that will cause very little back-emf and you probably don't need an MOV for that however, surge voltages from indirect lightning can easily cause 1500 volt peaks on the AC feed.

Comment: I am unsure how to calculate the back-emf when the ssr deactivates. Yes I will properly spec a MOV for surge voltages from lightning but I was wondering if I need to over spec it to take into account the energy from switching off the ssr. The manufacturer recommends a mov and a r-c snubber when used for inductive loads but I cannot find any recommendation for resistive loads.

Comment: @realmgod well, you have peak current at the point of deactivating the SSR and, you have copper inductance (mentioned in your question). The energy that is stored is \$\frac{1}{2}L\cdot I^2\$. It's probably not much (a few milli joules) given that you mentioned 50 uH but, it's for you to decide.